# Partitioned IOC Containers

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, unity-container, structuremap

I'm currently porting a large WIN app so I can extend it out to MVC. One of the principals is that it support multiple DALs which is dynamically bound by fluent config. for example

```
interface IDataStore
{
}

class SqlRepository :IDataStore
{
//do sql stuff
} 

class VistaDBRepository : IDataStore
{
//do vista db stuff
}
```

and finally

```
class WCFClientRepository :IDataStore
{
//do WFC stuff
}
```

to consume this implementation in the business logic it goes like this

```
public IDataStore GetCurrentStore()
{
    get
    {
        switch(EnterpriseConfiguration.Instance.ActiveProvider)
        {
            case "MSSQL":
               return new SqlRepository();
            case "VistaDB":
               return new VistaDBRespository();
            case "WFC":
               return new WCFReposity();
         }
    }
}

void GetDate()
{
   using(IDataStore db = GetCurrentStore())
   {
      //do something with db
   }
}
```

with that there is a connection listener that will monitor between the primary db provider (SQL) and the mobile provider (WCF) if the connection drops or is not available with the primary provider it will elect the secondary provider (WFC) as primary. this is to support mobile users and works great, user who are inside the LAN go directly to SQL and will auto switch to WFC when they leave.

finally VistaDB is used as a persistance store (plugin info, form metadata, locality, countries etc....)

I want to replace this pattern with a IOC container, my idea would be to build up a container for each defined IDataStore that can bind to a name, in turn get consumes as such

```
SQLReposity db = Container.Resolve<IDataStore>().ContainerName("MSSQL");
VistaDBReposity db = Container.Resolve<IDataStore>().ContainerName("VistaDB");
WFCReposity db = Container.Resolve<IDataStore>().ContainerName("WCF");
```

Any ideas on would to build out the container using Unity or StructureMap?

Comment: Does your application change data stores at runtime?  Or is this a one-time startup selection?

Comment: yes datastore changes during runtime depending on what database is being consumes

Answer (score 1):

Although you can create multiple containers for your application, this is generally discouraged. Having multiple containers can complicate your DI configuration, because it is much harder to share instances between containers and it will become much harder for the container to help you verifying your DI configuration.

In general I would only use multiple containers in case the application consists of multiple isolated modules, that share almost nothing. In all other scenarios, go with one single global container instance.

When looking at your design, my first thought is: why does the business layer have to know that there are multiple `IDatabase` implementations? Your design seems to communicate this by exposing the `GetCurrentStore()` method.

Instead, I would opt making this transparent and hidden from the business layer. Doing so makes the consuming code simpler, because it doesn't have to know that there are multiple stores. This makes the API smaller and therefore simpler. Easier to read, easier to test.

Making this transparent means that you will have to create an `IDatabase` implementation that is able to dispatch and fallback to the right implementation. This means that this 'dispatcher' can internally call the `GetCurrentStore()`, but can hide this from the rest of the application. This might also be the place to implement retry logic and the place to implement the fallback behavior.

I imagine this implementation to look something like this:

```
public class DatabaseDispatcher : IDatabase
{
    private readonly SQLReposity primaryStore;
    private readonly WFCReposity fallbackStore;
    private readonly VistaDBReposity persistentStore;

    public DatabaseDispatcher(
        SQLReposity primaryStore,
        WFCReposity fallbackStore,
        VistaDBReposity persistentStore) {
        this.primaryStore = primaryStore;
        this.fallbackStore = fallbackStore;
        this.persistentStore = persistentStore;
    }

    // IDatabase methods here. Example:
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
        try {
            return GetCurrentStore().Execute<TResult>(query);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // Decide what to do here. Is primary store offline? Then fallback
        }
    }

    private IDatabase GetCurrentStore() {
       // complex fallback logic here.
    }
}
```

This `DatabaseDispatcher` implementation is a piece of infrastructure that can be placed in your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). You might have multiple applications with different dispatching strategies. As you can see this implementation takes a hard dependency on the concrete repository types. This makes it really easy to register/resolve this type as follows:

```
// Ninject
kernel.Bind<IDatabase>().To<DatabaseDispatcher>();

// Unity
container.RegisterType<IDatabase, DatabaseDispatcher>();

// Simple Injector
container.Register<IDatabase, DatabaseDispatcher>();
```

Letting the `DatabaseDispatcher` depend on abstractions only is also possible and you can easily do this without using named registrations:

```
// Ninject
kernel.Bind<IDatabase>().ToMethod(c => new DatabaseDispatcher(
    primaryStore: kernel.Get<SQLReposity>(),
    fallbackStore: kernel.Get<WFCReposity>(),
    persistentStore: kernel.Get<VistaDBReposity>()));

// Unity
container.Register<IDatabase>(new InjectionFactory(c => new DatabaseDispatcher(
    primaryStore: c.Resolve<SQLReposity>(),
    fallbackStore: c.Resolve<WFCReposity>(),
    persistentStore: c.Resolve<VistaDBReposity>())));

// Simple Injector
container.Register<IDatabase>(() => new DatabaseDispatcher(
    primaryStore: container.GetInstance<SQLReposity>(),
    fallbackStore: container.GetInstance<WFCReposity>(),
    persistentStore: container.GetInstance<VistaDBReposity>()));
```

This allows you to have one single DI container instance, which can drastically reduce the complexity of your Composition Root.

Another thing that I noticed is that your `IDatabase` abstraction seems to implement `IDisposable`. This makes `IDatabase` a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) - a specific form of a [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) violation, because:

> Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on
>   abstractions.

The fact that there is anything to dispose is an implementation detail and the consumer should not have to know about this. So instead you should implement `IDisposable` only on the implementations, IF all implementations even need to dispose anyway. Instead of letting the consumer dispose, let your container manage the lifetime of your database instances. And especially because you might want to cache those database instances for the duration of a request, you don't want to expose a `Dispose` method to the consumers, because that would allow them to dispose that instance, while the request hasn't finished, and the instance still needs to be used by other code.

Comment: Steven I love your guidance tx.. however the issue is a bitter bigger then what was stated. the relationship between the UI and the BL is Typed Datasets wrapped around a custom serializer so that I can share an instance of the dataset with the BL and other UI controls. so there is that holding me down. ripping out datasets is not an option because the whole UI component rendering is based on attributes that are stored in the DB mapped to datacolumns in the datatable. also for every form there could be 20 user controls that gets loaded at runtime based on plugin logic in the DB mapped to DS

Comment: this is the driving factor as too why there is multiple DBs MS SQL or Oracle for business data and local vista db for UI/Plugin etc... furthermore during app startup there is a bootstrap process to sync vistadb with the main database.  given legacy datasets are weighing me down CRUD actions are called up the enharitance tree to the baseclass by getting access to the dataset via virtual property calling the base Bl to loaddataset/updatedataset flowing through to CurrentProvider finally calling EntLib5 database

Comment: I'm sure you can see the problem I have in front of me

Comment: Hi @RobertTheArchitect, I understand the legacy situation you are in, but I'm unsure how this affects my advice. Your question is about how to register your `IDatabase` and the fact that you return typed datasets doesn't change that as far as I see. Even better, typed datasets are drastically better than untyped, because this probably allows  you to apply a design [such as this one](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) without much trouble.